# "COPY_ERROR: Unable to copy" while using drush make with download type "copy"

Tags: 7, drush

Here is my module structure:

```
.
|-- mymodule.make
|-- mymodule.info
|-- mymodule.module
|-- mymodule.install
`-- sub1
    |-- sub1.make
    |-- sub1.info
    |-- sub1.module
    `-- sub1.install
```

I would like that when using `drush make` the sub-module `sub1` is also made (so I would like that `sub1.make` is called too).

In `mymodule.make` I declare:

```
api = "2"
core = "7.x"

projects[drupal][version] = "7.39"

; Modules
projects[sub1][type] = module
projects[sub1][download][type] = copy
projects[sub1][download][url] = "./sub1"
```

And here is the error that I have:

```
Found makefile: mymodule.make                                [ok]
COPY_ERROR: Unable to copy sub1 from ./sub1. -- build forced [warning]
```

However, the [documentation](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/#project-download-options) tells

> `download[type] = copy` Copies a project from a local folder.

so I think I'm using the correct `[download][type]`...

I've also tried with `projects[sub1][download][url] = "file://./sub1"` and have the same error.

Comment: Did you check is not simply a file permission issue?

Comment: Actually I've checked that and it's not the issue here, no file permission problems...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I used the `includes[]` directive instead.

Here is my working `mymodule.make`:

```
api = "2"
core = "7.x"

projects[drupal][version] = "7.39"

; Modules
includes[] = ./sub1/sub1.make
```